# Server 2008 Unresponsive But Has Network

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, terminal-server

I have a server running Windows Server 2008 x64 that stopped responding to ping and can't be connected to via TS.  However, when I got on the machine directly, I was able to ping, access internet, etc., just fine.  That is, the server can ping anything on the network, but not vice versa, even from another server in the same rack, same switch, etc. In further weirdness, I *can* browse the server through explorer, open / edit files that are shared from it, etc., just fine.

Unfortunately, in the interests of "I need TS to be working *now*", I rebooted the server and that made the problem go away, but in case it crops up again, anybody have any ideas on what the problem might have been (and more importantly, if there's a way to resolve it without rebooting)?

Comment: So you _can_ ping it now?

Comment: Yes, I can ping it, log on via mstsc, etc., all working as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have updates pending a restart? I have found in some cases, and actually this month with some of our 2003 servers (and possibly 2008 as well) that if you have a server which has had windows update run but not rebooted to complete the updates you can have this exact situation you describe.

Comment: Oh dear God....  Yet another reason not to use auto update on servers.

Comment: No, I didn't have any pending restart, but I did have some pending installation (I have AU set to download, but let me decide when to apply updates).  I suppose that's a possibility, but it worked yesterday.  I don't think any new updates came out in the last 20 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with Win2008R2 not knowing where it is located.  So the much more restrictive public firewall profile settings kick in having the effect you describe.  Hovering over the network icon (at least on Win2008R2) tells you what network location it thinks it is in.